# Is my proof of showing "4rs is even" correct?

Tags: solution-verification

For my study I need to write proofs. I have a hard time understanding that if my answer isn't the same as in the solution book, if it then can still be correct.

**The Question given is :**
"Prove that $4rs$ is even , with $r$ & $s$ Integers"

**Here's the proof I have written :**

I assume here that a proof of $4rs$ can be written in multiple ways.

Assume that r and s are particular intergers. 
It is given that the number is $4rs$. 
It can be written as $4rs=2(2rs)$ 
Let $t= 2rs$ and note that $t$ is an integer.
Hence, there exists an integer $t$ such that $4rs=2t$ 
Therefore, $4rs$ is even.

**This is the answer given in the solution book :**

assume that $r$ and $s$ are particular integers 
It is given that the number is $4rs$ 
It can be written as $4rs=2(2rs)$ 
Since r and s are integers, so are $r·s$ and $2rs$, specifically, even integers 
therefore, $2(2rs)$ is an even integer 
therefore, $4rs$ is an even integer

Is my proof also correct? 
Any feedback is much appreciated

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes your proof is correct. You have just explained that its even by taking another variable `t` which is completely fine.

Comment: Yes, it's correct. By the definition of even numbers, any number that can be written in the form of 2n is an even number, so by showing that 4rs can be written as 2t, where t is an integer, it proves that 4rs is even.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!